# How can I set a global show delay for v-b-tooltips?

Tags: tooltip, bootstrap-vue

The show delay of a [Bootstrap Vue tooltip](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/directives/tooltip/) can be set adding a `.dXXX` modifier, like so:

```
<b-button v-b-tooltip.d300 title="Tooltip content">Hover Me</b-button>
```

Is there a way to configure the default show delay globally?  I'd like to add a small delay to all tooltips by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation:

> Is there a way to configure the default show delay globally?

Not currently.  However, I've submitted a PR to add this feature: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/pull/3426

Once merged, the `delay` of both tooltips and popovers can be customized globally like so:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import BVConfig from 'bootstrap-vue/es/bv-config';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';

Vue.use(BVConfig, {
  BTooltip: {
    delay: {
      show: 400,
      hide: 100,
    },
  },
  BPopover: {
    delay: 1000,
  },
});

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

Comment: This has been merged and exists in versions >2.0.0-rc.22. Also, we don't need to import `BVConfig` and can simply pass a second Options object to the `Vue.use(BootstrapVue, { ...options });` line. The config object above in the answer is valid however, and works great!